# Is there .NET SDK to get table storage SAS key with AAD authentication

Tags: azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

I know I can acquire AAD token to storage account and use Resource manager to get table storage SAS key via REST API like below:

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/res7439/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/sto1299/ListServiceSas?api-version=2019-06-01
```

I am wondering if there is easier way to do this via .NET SDK?

Comment: Is this what you want?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet

Comment: Is that you want to create Azure storage service sas token? If so, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-service-sas-create-dotnet

Comment: Thanks, but they are not what I want, Basically I want this: 1) Acquire AAD token to storage account 2) Create storage account with AAD token 3) Get the SAS key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, we can use the sdk `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent` to Implement it.

For example

1. create a service principal  (I use Azure CLI to do that)

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# the sp will have Azure Contributor role
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric"
```

[image]

2. Create Azure storage account

```
 AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                      clientId, // the sp appId
                      clientSecret, // the sp password
                      tenantId, // the sp tenant  
                       AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                   .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                   .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                   .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                   .Build();
           var storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(restClient);
            storageClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptions;
          var groupName = "";
            var accountName = "";
            var storageCreateParams = new StorageAccountCreateParameters {
                Kind = Kind.Storage,
                Location = "",
                AccessTier = AccessTier.Hot,
                Sku = new SkuInner {
                    Name = SkuName.StandardLRS
                }



            };
           await storageClient.StorageAccounts.CreateAsync(groupName,accountName, storageCreateParams)
```

3. Create sas token for Azure table

```
 AzureCredentials credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
                      clientId, // the sp appId
                      clientSecret, // the sp password
                      tenantId, // the sp tenant  
                       AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            RestClient restClient = RestClient.Configure()
                                   .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                                   .WithCredentials(credentials)
                                   .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                                   .Build();
           var storageClient = new StorageManagementClient(restClient);
            storageClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptions;
            ServiceSasParameters serviceSas = new ServiceSasParameters { 
               CanonicalizedResource= "/table/<accountName>/<tableName>",
               Permissions=Permissions.Parse("raud"),
              SharedAccessExpiryTime= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(4)

            };
            var r =await storageClient.StorageAccounts.ListServiceSASAsync("<groupName>", "<accountName>", serviceSas);
            var sasToken=r.ServiceSasToken
```